# ANTLR4 techniques for LARGE files - breaking up the parsing tree

Tags: java, parsing, out-of-memory, antlr4

I have a working ANTLR4 compiler which works well for files up to ~300Mb, if I set the JAVA VM size to 8G with -Xmx8G.   However larger files crash the parser/compiler with a HEAP out of memory message.   I have been advised to check my code for memory consumption outside of the ANTLR4 process. (data below)  I'm using token factory and unbufferedChar and token streams.

One strategy I'm working with is to test the size of the INPUT file/stream, (if knowable), in my case it is.   If the file is small, parse using my top level rule which generates a parse tree that is large, but works for small files.

If the file is larger than an arbitrary threshold, I attempt to divide the parsing into chunks, by selecting a sub-rule.  So for small files I parse the rule patFile (existing working code), for large files I'm exploring breaking things up by parsing sub rule "patFileHeader", followed by parsing the rule "bigPatternRec" which replaces the "patterns+" portion of the former rule.
In this way my expectation is that I can control how much of the token stream  is read in.

At the moment this looks promising, but I see issues with controlling how much ANTLR4 parses when processing the header.  I likely have a grammar rule that causes the patFileHeader to consume all available input tokens before exiting.  Other cases seem to work, but I'm still testing.  I'm just not sure that this approach to solving "large file" parsing is viable.

SMALL file Example Grammar:

```
patFile         :   patFileHeader patterns+
//                  {System.out.println("parser encountered patFile");}
                ;
patFileHeader   :   SpecialDirective? includes* gbl_directives* patdef  
                ;               
patterns        :   patdata+ patEnd
//                  {System.out.println("parser encountered patterns");}
                ;
bigPatternRec   :   patdata 
                |   patEnd
                ;
...
```

In my case for a small file, I create the parse tree with:

```
   parser = new myparser(tokens);
   tree = parser.patFile();           // rule that parses to EOF
   walker=walk(mylisteners,tree);
```

Which will parse the entire file to EOF.

For larger files I considered the following technique:

```
  // Process the first few lines of the file
  tree = parser.patFileHeader();     // sub rule that does not parse to EOF
  walker=walk(mylisteners,tree);

  //
  // Process remaining lines one line/record at a time
  //
  while( inFile.available() ) {
          parser = new myParser(tokens);
          tree = parser.bigPatternRec();
          walker=walk(mylisteners,tree);
  }
```

In response to a suggestion that I profile the behavior, I have generated this screenshot of JVMonitor on the "whole file" during processing of my project.
One thing of intrest to me was the three Context sets of ~398Mb. In my grammar vec is a component of vecdata, so it appears that some context data is getting replicated.  I may play with that.   It's possible that the char[] entry is my code outside of ANTLR4.  I'd have to disable my listeners and run to generate the parse tree witihout my code active to be sure.  I do other things that consume memory (MappedByteBuffers) for high speed file I/O on output, which will contribute to exceeding the 8Gb image.
[image: JVMMonitorShot]

What is interesting however, is what happens to the memory image if I break the calls up and JUST process subrules. The memory consumption is ~%10 of the full size, and the ANTLR4 objects are not even on the radar in that case.  [image: SubruleJVMMonitor]

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code"_ are considered off-topic.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: The problem is not with the size of your source! A complex Antlr grammar running in an 8Gig VM can handle 1Gig source files without any problem. Antlr effectively keeps only one copy of the source in VM memory. The problem must lay in whatever else you are doing. Profile to pinpoint what is consuming so much memory. Also agree with the prior comment.

Comment: @Jim Garrisson Thanks for the feedback.  I have improved the question, let me know if this is better.   Also the point regarding ANTLR effectively maintaining only 1 copy in source, I will do some profiling as well.

Comment: @GRosenberg  I have done some initial profiling.  I haven't broken the project up into "run with my listeners" (which consume memory), and "dont run with listeners".   So far I just profiled ANTLR4 start rule parsing the entire 1.5GB file vs a two ANTLR4 rules designed to parse only portions of the file.